# Make Mac to treat my iPhone like a regular wifi router. I want it to constantly stay connected to my iPhone (XS)

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, wifi

There is a difference how the Mac sees Hotspots and regular Wifi routers, it disconnects from HotSPOT as soon as it goes to sleep and needs to be reconnected after waking up. I have the same iCloud on my Mac and iPhone and I can connect via "iCloud instant HotSpot" but, I also want it to stay connected **all the time.**